# Is HVAC heat pump condenser better mounted to a wall or a flat roof?

Tags: roof, heat-pump

My home has a split flat roof.  One section is 3' taller than the other.  I'm considering replacing my gas furnace with heat pump.  Would it be better to install the condenser unit on top of the flat roof, or mounted to a bracket on the wall that is pictured.  I prefer wall because its less holes in the roof.  I'd also like to use this wall to mount conduit access down to the basement for future: solar, amateur weather station, electric outlet, HP lineset, etc.  Second pic is an example of the type of condenser that would be installed.

[image: flat roof]
nevermind the fresh stucco. this pic is years old

[image: sample condenser unit]

Comment: If you would set this on the roof, it would have to be on a raised platform to avoid immersion of the lower part of the unit in heavy rains.  Best mounting would be on a wall. The low wall might have to have a bracket mounted on top to in effect extend the wall upward because the wall mounting bracket of the unit might require attachment near the top of the condensing unit. Study the design of the wall mounting bracket. The whole system would have to be able to withstand expected wind forces.

Comment: Third option: Mine sits on the ground, with a framework holding up a few feet so it stays out of snow or flooding.

Comment: Usually you want to reduce holes in a roof, unless needed/only choice.

Comment: it's pedantic, but when used as a heat pump, that's the evaporator.

Comment: The answer profoundly depends on where you are and whether you plan to use it for heating, cooling or both. Do you experience sub-freezing temperatures?

Answer (score 9):

The condenser you show is common to mini split systems and work better when in the shade.

Since the roof offers no shade, I would recommend a wall mounting. Most manufacturers offer a wall mounting bracket designed for their units.

You may want to consider mounting on the wall lower down one side of the house. You have to consider the lines and the electric as well.  In some locations a 120V outlet must be nearby also.

Consider all these factors before choosing a final installation area.

Comment: Ehhh.... Heat pump condensers working better in the shade? Airco condensers obviously, but heat pump? Do you have more info on why this is the case?

Answer (score 5):

If you would set this on the roof, it would have to be on a raised platform to avoid immersion of the lower part of the unit in heavy rains.

Best mounting would be on a wall. The low wall might have to have an improvised framework mounted on top to in effect extend the wall upward because the wall mounting bracket of the unit might require attachment near the top of the condensing unit. Study the design of the wall mounting bracket. The whole system would have to be able to withstand expected wind forces.

The best mounting might be on a lower side wall near where the air handler would be located on an inside wall. Of course some of these minisplit condensing units can feed multiple air handlers and so the refrigerant lines must be routed through an attic or through trusses to get to the more distant air handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Since those create a lots of vibration between the compressor and huge fan, a floor mount would be the best.

Wall mount should be on studs.

Roof mount is problematic as you say.

Comment: These minisplit condensing units are commonly mounted on walls. I am under the impression that they have practically no detectable vibration.

Comment: @ Jim Stewart, You are correct. The units are far quieter and have less vibrations than the common ground mounted Heat pump condensers.  The fans are big, but because of that they move a lot of air and do not need to spin fast. (relatively)